# C General sscanf return

Tags: file, scanf

I'm trying to use the return value of sscanf function. The problem is that in the file that I'm reading, some lines may contain different number of integers. How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: Why the f**** have you changed your question from C to C# ??

Comment: What's with this edit to change C to C#, and with an accepted answer to boot?  If you want to ask a different question, then pose it *as* its own, separate question.  **This** question makes no sense in C# context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int values[5];
int values_per_line = sscanf_s(line_buffer, "%d %d %d %d %d", &values[0], &values[1], &values[2], &values[3], &values[4]);
```

`

#### [sscanf_s, _sscanf_s_l, swscanf_s, _swscanf_s_l](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3.aspx):

> #### Return Value
>
> Each of these functions [including s_sscanf()] **returns the number of fields that are successfully converted and assigned;** the return value does not include fields that were read but not assigned. A return value of 0 indicates that no fields were assigned. The return value is EOF for an error or if the end of the string is reached before the first conversion.

Comment: @Bobbydickson The function will \*try\* to read 5 integers and report back how many of those could be read.